# Saving an image using node (fs writeStreams) inserts headers into file

Tags: ios, node.js, http

I am trying to upload a photo (in a multipart form) from an iOS app, using `AFNetworking`. I am using node.js for my backend, and almost have it working. The problem is that when I am trying to save the image it is also writing the headers to the file...So all of the images I save have something like this in the beginning (when I open the image in plain text):

```
--Boundary+9EF923E9CAACB213
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="para"

val
--Boundary+9EF923E9CAACB213
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="afImage"; filename="afImage.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

The server code I am using is:

uploadIOS: (req, res) ->

```
tmpfile = variables.uploadsDir + "tempname"
ws = fs.createWriteStream(tmpfile)

req.on 'data', (data) ->
  ws.write data

req.on 'end', ->
  ws.end()
```

I can get it working using the express body parser, but would prefer to do it this way if possible. Any ideas how to strip away the headers?

Comment: these are not headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a multipart-capable parser such as [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) or [multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty).

Comment: I was using multiparty at one point but was hoping I could get away without it. Thanks!